# Hibernate One to many mapping override

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate

I am facing a hibernate problem in updainting the join table in one to many mapping with hibernate. Below are my two entity class and join table entity class.
ArticleCategoryMap.java

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "ARTICLECATEGORYMAP")
    public class ArticleCategoryMap {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5653708523600543988L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @Column ( name = "id")
    Long id;


    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = Article.class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, optional = true, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ARTICLE_ID", nullable = true, insertable = true, updatable = true)
    private Article article;


    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = Category.class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, optional = true, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JoinColumn(name = "CATEGORY_ID", nullable = true, insertable = true, updatable = true)
    private Category category;

   //setter and getter  
}
```

Article.java

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "ARTICLE")
    public class Article {
    private long id;
    private String title;
    private String description;
    private String keywords;
    private String content;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "ARTICLE_ID")
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }
   //setter and getter  
    }
```

Category.java

```
  @Entity
    @Table(name = "CATEGORY")
    public class Category {

    private long id;
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "ARTICLECATEGORYMAP",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "CATEGORY_ID"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "ARTICLE_ID")
    )
    @CollectionId(
            columns = @Column(name="id"), 
            type=@Type(type="long"), 
            generator = "sequence"
    )
    private Collection<Article> articles;



    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "CATEGORY_ID")
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "ARTICLECATEGORYMAP",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "CATEGORY_ID"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "ARTICLE_ID")
    )
    @CollectionId(
            columns = @Column(name="id"), 
            type=@Type(type="long"), 
            generator = "sequence"
    )
    // setter an getter
    }
```

Now suppose first time I have 2 elements in article table which is mapping to one entry of the category table. so the join table will look something like 
[image]

Now due to some reason, I want to update the entry where the article entry will map to a new category ID. So the final DB should look like 
[image]

So My problem Is how can I update this join table.

Comment: so basically you have a `ManyToMany` relationship and not a `OneToMany`. Otherwise you wouldn't need a Join-Table

Comment: Your mapping is wrong. Read the Hibernate manual. It has examples and explanations for every collection mapping. You shouldn't have a Collection<Article> in Category. You should have a Collection<ArticleCategoryMap>, annotated with `@OneToMany(mappedBy = "category")`. Or you could ditch the ArticleCategoryMap entity completely and use a ManyToMany between Article and Category.

Answer (score 0):

If you want **one to many** relationship (1 category have many articles and 1 article to 1 category) you dont need a join table.

The entity classes should look like that:

**Category Entity:**

Contains a Set of articles:

```
   @Entity
    @Table(name = "CATEGORY")
    public class Category {

    private long id;
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="category")
        private Set<Article> articles;

          ......
    }
```

**Article Entity:**

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "ARTICLE")
    public class Article {

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="id", nullable=false)
    private Category category;

    private long id;
    private String title;
    private String description;
    private String keywords;
    private String content;

    .......
    }
```

For more details take a look at [hibernate-one-to-many](http://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-one-to-many). Hope this helps.

Also move annotation from methods to fields. This:

```
private long id;

@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name = "CATEGORY_ID")
public long getId() {
    return id;
}
```

Should be:

```
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "CATEGORY_ID")
    private long id;

   public long getId() {
        return id;
    }
```

**Many to many relationship:**

At your database you have 3 tables:

> 1. CATEGORY
> 2. ARTICLE
> 3. ARTICLECATEGORYMAP (join table)

For many to many relationship entities would be:

**Category Entity:**

```
    @Entity
        @Table(name = "CATEGORY")
        public class Category {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue
        @Column(name = "CATEGORY_ID")
        private long id;
        private String name;

       @ManyToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
       @JoinTable(
        name = "ARTICLECATEGORYMAP", 
        joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "CATEGORY_ID") }, 
        inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "ARTICLE_ID") }
    )
    Set<Article > articles = new HashSet<>();
     .....
   }
```

**Article Entity:**

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "ARTICLE")
    public class Article {


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "ARTICLE_ID") 
    private long id;
    private String title;
    private String description;
    private String keywords;
    private String content;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "articles")
    private Set<Category> categories = new HashSet<>();

    .......
    }
```

For more info take a look at [many-to-many ralationship](http://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-many-to-many)

Comment: @java guy: Thank you for the detailed answer, but I have to use the join table for keeping the future in mind that the association can change from "one to many" to "many to many". SO i have to use this join table concept. Please help me, is it possible to directly override the join table with new value or first I have to remove the first association and make a new entry.